# Trying to get the server to wait for the client (Socket Programming)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to get my server to wait for my clients response. I am trying to get username and password from my client. This is my clients function:

```
 /* Wait for the game to start. */
    do {
        recv_msg(sockfd, msg);
        char username[9], password[9];
        if (!strcmp(msg, "USN")){
            printf("\nUsername: \n");
            scanf("%s", username);
            write_server_msg(sockfd, username);
        }

        if (!strcmp(msg, "PSW")){
            printf("\nPassword: \n");
            scanf("%c", password);
            write_server_msg(sockfd, password);
        }
    } while ( strcmp(msg, "SRT") );
```

This is my server side:

```
void authenticate_process(int cli_sockfd){

    /* Authentication Process */
    write(cli_sockfd, "USN", sizeof(int));
    printf("MADE IT");
    char *username;
    username = recv_msg(cli_sockfd);
    printf("[DEBUG] Client username is %s.\n", username);

    write(cli_sockfd, "PSW", sizeof(int));
    char *password;
    password = recv_msg(cli_sockfd);
    printf("[DEBUG] Client Password is %s.\n", password);
    write(cli_sockfd, "SRT", sizeof(int));

}
```

My terminal output is the following for client:

```
Username: 
morgan
Game over.
```

My terminal output of server is:

```
DEBUG] Client username is morgan.
[DEBUG] Client Password is .
```

I can not get the function to move into the 'password' section of code correctly. It somehow moves into it but never prompts the user for their input but instead it seems to move forward on its own. My receive message function on server side looks like this:

```
char *recv_msg(int sockfd)
{
    int length;
    char *msg;
    msg = (char*) malloc (9);

    int n = read(sockfd, msg, 9);

    free(msg);
    return msg;

}
```

Is there something i am missing? I just want my code to prompt the user for its username then prompt it for its password.

Comment: Why `sizeof(int)`? What's in write_server_msg? What's in read_msg?

Comment: Why are you freeing a pointer and then returning it?